# std::min / std::max with "intrinsic-like"

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm rewriting a library where one of the "interfaces" is a global numeric variable (don't ask).

I'm replacing it with a global object of a UDT that acts like a numeric, supporting `operator int() const`

Some in-house consumers of my library use std::max with that global. They will get compilation errors because std::max only expects a single T.

For example:

```
PseudoInt x;  // in library

// in consumer
void conumser()
{
    int y = std::max(5, x);  // will error now, because int and PseudoInt are not the same T
}
```

I'd optimally like my consumers to not have to react, by doing things like `std::max<int>(5, x)`.

Am I out of luck here?

Comment: Why not write your own max function that takes a `PseudoInt` and then hand it off to `std::max`?

Comment: Maybe if you create an implicit constructor from int to that data type and a template specialization for std::max? But the explicit call with int as the template argument won't work then.

Comment: Don't add implicit constructors! Ew!

Comment: @languitar, no, it won't - since `std::max` is a template, it won't perform implicit conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `std::max` is a template, you can provide a specialization for `std::max` with your PseudoInt and Int.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I thought about this. I was looking for a more general purpose solution that handles all algorithms, not just std::max. I should have made that more explicit in my question. If I don't see any magic bullet (and I don't think there is one, tbh), I'll mark this as the accepted solution.

Comment: I have this working, thanks - My PseudoInt is a little more complicated than original spec'ed. It's a template. 
PseudoGlobal template<typename NUMERIC_T, typename PSEUDONUMERIC_T>
 NUMERIC_T max(NUMERIC_T a, PseudoGlobal<PSEUDONUMERIC_T> b)
 {
  return std::max(a, static_cast<NUMERIC_T>(b));
 }
...